# Java Error Double Free or Corruption (Memory)

Tags: java, jvm

could someone help me on this error, I've never seen it, it's a bug of JDK or was created by a burst of memory?

I'm using: jdk1.6.0_21

The beginning of my error:

```
*** glibc detected *** java: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007f3f00410020 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x75018)[0x7f3f93d75018]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6c)[0x7f3f93d79f6c]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8(CRYPTO_free+0x19)[0x7f3efe8d9b09]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8(OBJ_NAME_add+0xa4)[0x7f3efe8db3a4]
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8(EVP_add_cipher+0x1b)[0x7f3efe9191eb]
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8(SSL_library_init+0x38)[0x7f3efebd8738]
/usr/lib64/libcups.so.2(httpInitialize+0x5d)[0x7f3eff9017cd]
/usr/lib64/libcups.so.2(httpConnectEncrypt+0x95)[0x7f3eff9018d5]
/domain/.p_java/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/lib/amd64/headless/libmawt.so(Java_sun_print_CUPSPrinter_canConnect+0x46)[0x7f3effc26c36]
[0x7f3f8f486c88]
======= Memory map: ========
40000000-40009000 r-xp 00000000 fd:19 65673                              /domain/.p_java/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/java
40108000-4010a000 rwxp 00008000 fd:19 65673                              /domain/.p_java/java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin/java
4010a000-4093a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK or Oracle JDK?

Comment: Seems like it is a bug: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6513889

Comment: I'm using the Oracle JDK. 


My system does not use swing components, can he get this same behavior that is described in error?

Comment: The "type" of the error seems to be the same, but the **reason** seems to be entirely different. This one obviously seems to stem from some encrypted HTTP connection. Websearches including "httpConnectEncrypt" bring narrower results (e.g. http://bugs.caucho.com/view.php?id=3449 ) but no conclusion. Is this bug reproducible?

Answer (score 1):

A double free problem would usually means a bug in the jvm or some library it uses.

The backtrace is similar to [Bug Report](http://bugs.caucho.com/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=3449). The bug report indicates that there's a known issue with openssl 0.9.8 so it's worth upgrading openssl, which might also require upgrading packages that depend on it (cups/java etc).

Comment: This error I can not reproduce it is happening from time to time
Is there any way to fix or work around this error?