# *** glibc detected *** java: double free or corruption (out)

Tags: java, crash

My Java application occasionally crash with only the following error message:

```
*** glibc detected *** /data/apps/jdk/bin/java: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fc6d829abb0 ***
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /lib64/libc.so.6[0x3ab78760e6]
    /lib64/libc.so.6[0x3ab7878c13]
    /data/apps/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/libkcms.so(+0x3e73b)[0x7fc6e483f73b]
    /data/apps/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/libkcms.so(Java_sun_java2d_cmm_kcms_CMM_cmmFreeProfile+0x28)[0x7fc6e484ca48]
    [0x7fc714be9d98]
    ======= Memory map: ========
    [0x7fc714be9d98]
    ======= Memory map: ========
    00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fc:10 4458494                            /data/apps/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java
    00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 fc:10 4458494                            /data/apps/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java
    02325000-023c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
    77fe00000-782d80000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    782d80000-785000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    785000000-795200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    795200000-7d7000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    7d7000000-800000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    33c2000000-33c2017000 r-xp 00000000 fc:02 1572920                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
    33c2017000-33c2217000 ---p 00017000 fc:02 1572920                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
    33c2217000-33c2218000 r--p 00017000 fc:02 1572920                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
    33c2218000-33c2219000 rw-p 00018000 fc:02 1572920                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
    33c2219000-33c221d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    3ab7000000-3ab7020000 r-xp 00000000 fc:02 1573278                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
    3ab721f000-3ab7220000 r--p 0001f000 fc:02 1573278                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
    3ab7220000-3ab7221000 rw-p 00020000 fc:02 1573278                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
    3ab7221000-3ab7222000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
    3ab7400000-3ab7402000 r-xp 00000000 fc:02 1573281                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
    3ab7402000-3ab7602000 ---p 00002000 fc:02 1573281                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
    3ab7602000-3ab7603000 r--p 00002000 fc:02 1573281                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
    3ab7603000-3ab7604000 rw-p 00003000 fc:02 1573281                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
    3ab7800000-3ab798a000 r-xp 00000000 fc:02 1573279                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
    3ab798a000-3ab7b89000 ---p 0018a000 fc:02 1573279                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
    3ab7b89000-3ab7b8d000 r--p 00189000 fc:02 1573279                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
    3ab7b8d000-3ab7b8e000 rw-p 0018d000 fc:02 1573279                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
```

There is no other error message, here is the environment settings:

[root@xxx log]# java -version

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

[root@xxx log]# uname -a

```
Linux xxx 2.6.32-504.12.2.02.qiyi.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 12 11:44:09 CST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can anybody help me to figure out this? thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Error Double Free or Corruption (Memory)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454502/java-error-double-free-or-corruption-memory)

Comment: Looks like the detailed error message is different with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454502/java-error-double-free-or-corruption-memory.
Is there any solutions to solve it?